# Django Rest - Different view based on role

Tags: python, django

News to Django and Django Rest.

I'm trying to create 2 types of view, based on the role of the user.

While creating a new demand, I have *one field* that I would like to not show to one role(leaving it null in DB) but to show it to the other role.

The thing is that I don't see how I could do that.

If anyone could guide me in the right direction

Here is what I have :

models.py

```
class demand(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    assigned = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

serializer.py

```
class demandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.demand
        fields = ('title','description','assigned')
```

views.py

```
class demandCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset=models.demand.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers.demandSerializer
```

Comment: use a filter in the views.py to only list items that the user has access to

Comment: @Jawad the op is talking about _fields_ not records.

Comment: how are you differentiating users in your app? are you using the default user with an assigned workgroup?

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the request data before saving it.

```
class DemandCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Demand.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.DemandSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ... #do whatever check you want
        request.data.pop('assigned', None) # I've choose this parameter as an example
        return super(DemandCreateAPIView, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```